# angularjs $http call won't recognize headers

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I'm trying to hit an endpoint that works fine in Chrome's rest client. But for whatever reason, the browser gives me back the same unhelpful error no matter what I do. Here's the $http call:

```
         return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: calls.filters,
            headers: {
             accept: calls.acceptValue,
             Authorization: calls.token
            }
         }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
         });
```

I've tested and made sure that the calls obj is coming through, and all the values are there. But when I look at what's actually being sent when I do it this way, the headers look like this:

```
   {
       accept: "application/json", 
       Authorization:  "tokenstuffF82arSJxkQ"
   }
```

If I cut/paste that into the rest client, I get an error back that I'm sending malformed request. So in a desperate attempt to appease the $http gods, I created a headers var, as a string and dropped that into the headers: {} part of the call. I did it with single-quotes (ie 'accept:') and without (ie accept:), I did with & without curly braces. Not that I expected it to work, but scraping the bottom of the barrel on ideas at this point.

No matter what I do, though, I still get the same "Error, All requests must have Authorization header" error, even though the Authorization is in there! I have CORS enabled, plus I know the endpoint hittage works otherwise, since basically the same setup is how I'm logging in. How on earth do I get this to work, and what am I missing!?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check your dev tools for the Authorization header or event better check the request from a fiddler and compare the request you making from the rest client. i'm sure there would be something minor left out and that's eating your day.